# Mail Body has headers and Part Info

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

We have to send email to a distribution group when a value in DB changes. I have the code in place. It is same as the code in the below link -

[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_send_html_in_email.htm][1]

For your ready reference, I will add the code here -

```
    import java.util.Properties;

    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.MessagingException;
    import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;

import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendHTMLEmail {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "destinationemail@gmail.com";

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = "fromemail@gmail.com";
      final String username = "manishaspatil";//change accordingly
      final String password = "******";//change accordingly

      // Assuming you are sending email through relay.jangosmtp.net
      String host = "relay.jangosmtp.net";

      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
      props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

      // Get the Session object.
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
         new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
               return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
    });

      try {
            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

       // Set From: header field of the header.
       message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

       // Set To: header field of the header.
       message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
              InternetAddress.parse(to));

       // Set Subject: header field
       message.setSubject("Testing Subject");

       // Send the actual HTML message, as big as you like
       message.setContent(
              "<h1>This is actual message embedded in HTML tags</h1>",
             "text/html");

       // Send message
       Transport.send(message);

       System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

      } catch (MessagingException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
   }
}
```

This works fine from my local set up. However from the server , even the header info gets printed in the email and the subject line gets stripped off. I have searched internet looking for possible fixes. There is not much code also to debug. If you can get me some pointer, that would be really helpful. This is how the email looks -

```
> ----=_Part_1_12345.566 Content-Type:text/plain; charset=us-ascii Content-Transfer-Encoding:7bit
> 
> <<Actual Body>>
> ----=_Part_1_12345.566
```

Comment: Put session.setDebug(true) for more details.

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using on the server?  How are you configuring which version to use?